# How to use Word Break Opportunity tags in ReactJS button text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wbr

I have a user-defined value such as `1234_this_is_a_very_long_button_name_hello_world_12345_this_is_long` which is used as a button label and I need to have the button text wrap on the underscores.

I can insert a `<wbr>` after every underscore with simple string replace but then how can I set the `text` value as it escapes the `<wbr>` with `&lt;wbr&gt;`?

Is there an alternative way to do what I'm doing or is there a way to set a html fragment to the text value and have it not be escaped?

My button is defined as:

```
<ActionButton
id={desButtonId}
styles={descriptionBtnStyles}
text={button.description}
onClick={toggleIsDesCalloutVisible}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ActionButton`'s `text` property can take JSX children, you can do that like this:

```js
<ActionButton
    id={desButtonId}
    styles={descriptionBtnStyles}
    text={button.description
        .split('_')
        .map((x, i) => i ? ['_', <wbr />, x] : x)
    }
    onClick={toggleIsDesCalloutVisible}
/>
```

In React, arrays of elements are automatically flattened upon insertion, so you can return text and JSX elements together. In other words, `['a', ['_', <wbr />, 'b'], ...]` will be flattened into something with the HTML equivalent `a_<wbr>b...`.

If `ActionButton`'s `text` property only accepts a string, however, you'll need to figure out another way (e.g. can it alternatively take a `children` property?) or write your own custom button component.